# Sending arraylist<object> to another activity in android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

i have set of values in android listview. when i click submit button i want to get whole list in another activity. i tried with intent.putExtra(); but i am getting following error .

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.technical14.recyclers.Planet@4011368
```

My Code is -

```
proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ArrayList<Planet> apl = planetsList;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Proceed.class);
        intent.putExtra("QuestionListExtra", apl);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

i am new to the android. so please help me on this.

Comment: check my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43424961/6756514

Comment: post `Planet` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Planet` Parcelable using http://parcelabler.com/

and then send using

```
intent.putExtra("QuestionListExtra", apl);
```

and in `Proceed` activity

```
ArrayList<Planet> list = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("QuestionListExtra");
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the solution

1. Your model class should be implements Parcelable :

   ```
    public class Planet implements Parcelable {

   // Your setter and getter methods
    }
   ```
2. Put your arralist to putExtra() :

   ```
   ArrayList<Planet> contactList = // planets data;
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayContact.class);
   intent.putExtra("Contact_list", contactList);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

3.In second Activity:

```
    ArrayList<ContactClass> myList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Contact_list");
```